# Return to the previous activity preventing come back the the initial activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement a common behavior (I think).

I have 2 activities:
`LoginActivity` and `MainActity`.

The `MainActiviy` contains a menu with 3 fragments to navigate through them: `RequestFragment`, `DetailFragment` and `VisualizationFragment`.

But, I have one issues that I have not solved yet:

The first one, if the flow is similar to:
`LoginActivity` -> `MainActivity` -> `RequestFragment` -> `DetailFragment`
And also, you can navigate
`LoginActivity` -> `MainActivity` -> `VisualizationFragment`

But once, you are logged, remove the `LoginActivity` from the flow, just now I'm using:

**LoginActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
   //...some extra code...

   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//..start the activity

}
```

Ok, that is working ok, but in my `MainActivity` I have the issue:
**MainActivity**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Taking in consideration that I have a menu in my `MainActivity` replacing that one for my fragment, how I can navigate through my application closing the app (as is natural) when the `MainActivity` is open and come back to the previous when a `Fragment` is displayed?

Just now, my code is not doing anything with the navigation through the fragments, it's taking all as the `MainActivity` is open without taking in consideration the `fragments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backpressed code like below. I showed alert box if it meets the last fragment.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            showAlertDialog(Constants.EXIT_APP, Constants.APP_NAME);
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    }
```

//add this method to navigate. Write in a common java file

```
public void showFragment(Fragment fragment, String back_stack_name, boolean save_back) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        if(save_back) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(back_stack_name);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

//call this method wherever u need for fragment by:

```
Classname obj = new Classname();
showFragment(obj,"FRAGMENT_NAME_IN_STRING",true);
```

Note: If you want to add the fragment to backstack, set 3rd parameter as true otherwise set false.
As like Intent for calling a class, showFragment is used for calling a fragment.